# Validation Only With Play Json

Tags: scala, play-json

I'd like to use PlayJson to only validate multiple fields of some json and not map it to a custom object. I Only care about the Yes Or No answer to the validation criteria. Is it possible to use PlayJson in that way? So far I have something like,

```
val json = .....

val reads = (JsPath \ "foo").read[String](min(5)) and
      (JsPath \ "bar").read[String](max(10))

json.validate["I ONLY WANT TO VALIDATE NOT MAP"](reads) match {
  case s: JsSuccess => true
  case e: JsError => false
}
```

Thank you Stack Overflow community.

Comment: `.validate.isSuccess` that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deserialising to a case class model via `Reads[MyModel]` we can deserialise to a tuple via `Reads[(String, String)]` like so

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

val reads = (
  (JsPath \ "foo").read[String](minLength[String](5)) and
  (JsPath \ "bar").read[String](minLength[String](10))
).tupled

val json = Json.parse(
  """
    |{
    |  "foo": "abcde",
    |  "bar": "woohoowoohoo",
    |  "zar": 42
    |}
    |""".stripMargin)

json.validate(reads).isSuccess
```

which outputs

```
res0: Boolean = true
```

Note how we called `tupled` method when creating the reader, and `isSuccess` to get a boolean out of validation process.

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/JBjdt2Y/0

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The `.tupled` is what I was missing.